# Possibly infected kernel (odd system process)

Tags: windows, virus, process, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Has anyone seen/or knows anything identical to this:

[image]

`1515..:19699.exe` with a semicolon in the center?

Whenever I launch an app that lists the currently running processes (e.g. SysInternals "Process Explorer" or Nirsoft "cprocess"), they are immediately terminated and access rights are changed from the default valid ones to something different (I verified this with `cacls`).

I can no longer access the file, unless I take ownership of it (with `cacls` or through the Windows dialog box). As you can see, it runs under the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user.

I tried terminating this PID with `pstools`, namely `psexec -s`. That gives the running process `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` rights but to no avail. It also modifies the `.exes` in such a way that an additional "MS-DOS" tab is added to the file properties.

Comment: Boot sector viruses are common these days, see my post on how to remove it...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Answer (score 3):

colon in the middle usually means alternate data stream.  find the file named the left side of the colon.

Comment: C:\Windows\1515176842.exe; the size is 0 bytes and i can freely delete it. however, upon OS start - it is recreated.

Comment: @ellectroglow. Sounds like a virus to me!

Comment: then there's an additional executable you need to find

Comment: one option would be to create your own 151...whatever.exe that tries to disclose its parent process.  sorry not 151...exe but 151...exe:whatever.exe

Comment: i don't know if it's even possible, but you may be able to put a do nothing empty .exe there and change file permissions such that NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM is denied access when trying to execute or write to it.  maybe if that generated an error message you could use a sysinternals tool to get the parent process of the error message box...